# Python Scrapy - How to get these names without ignoring filters?

Tags: python, scrapy

I got this:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import PontsItems


class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'enseafr'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2010', ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PontsItems()

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="annuaire_result_list"]'):
            items['name'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            items['description'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get().strip()
            items['year'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get().strip()
        yield items
```

I know why this pulls only 1 position, question is how to iterate through all these positions and pull it all before going to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make the following changed:

```
def parse(self, response):

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="annuaire_result_list"]/div')[:-1]:
            items = {}
            items['name'] = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            items['description'] = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get().strip()
            items['year'] = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get().strip()
            yield items
```

you have to yield each item in the loop instead of yield only the last one

Comment: It only pulls one for me ;s

Comment: Nvm it pulls only 1 because there's only 1 "annuaire_result_list" - after looping through "single_desc" putting yield into a loop fixed it. Cheers buddy

Comment: I have updated the script in the answer, now it returns 10 rows

Comment: Hey man I'm trying to move to other pages using: next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="global-pagination"]/a[@class="next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)  but it moves me to same page again. Any ideas how to change that so it moves across pages? I set auto_throttle and download speed to make it gentle just fyi

Comment: The next page loads by AJAX call, so please check this call ```https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult``` on network tab in Chorome